# How to insert array Key's value if value is empty

Tags: php, arrays

Example

```
$arr1 = array("1","2","3","4");
$arr2 = array("red","","green","");
```

I have 2 arrays, I need to make this key and value so I am using here array_combine() function

```
$keyVal = array_combine($arr1,$arr2);
```

when I use this array_combine

> array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

This above error will be shown so I need to insert some dummy values where array values are empty, what can I do to this.

And this $arr2(array) values coming from input textbox,checkbox and radio buttons so I already tried that array_map function that only inserted the textbox null values not checkbox and radio buttons values.

Please, anyone, solve this issue. And thanking you spending time to reading this

Comment: are you expecting array("1" => "red","2" => "","3" => "green","4" => ""); as final result?

Comment: Please share the html part as well for better understanding

Comment: what php version do you have? On 7.4 your example works

Comment: print_r($keyVal); will give you the following output Array ( [1] => red [2] => [3] => green [4] => )

Comment: Please make the effort to at least show “examples”, that actually reproduce the problem. What you have shown here so far, doesn’t do that - https://3v4l.org/BtXQr _“Please, anyone, solve this issue.”_ - no actual issue to solve here yet. Please go read [ask] and [mre].